# A non-elliptic PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry

I wish to know if this PDE can be solved (for a real smooth function $\rho$)  on a compact complex surface X :
$\bar{\partial}\partial \rho \wedge \bar{\partial}\partial \rho + \bar{\partial}\partial \rho \wedge \bar{\partial}\partial \sigma + \bar{\partial}\partial \sigma \wedge \bar{\partial}\partial \sigma = 0$ where $\sigma$ is a given smooth real function on X. 
(Note that, one has solutions to this in $\mathbb{C}^2$ if $\sigma$ is real analytic). The problem is that the linearisation of this equation is not elliptic. The motivation for solving this is to produce a trivial line bundle with a hermitian metric so that its Chern character forms (not cohomology classes) are zero.

Comment: Could you explain the notations ? You are from the community of complex analysis, and people from classical PDEs may not understand. Thanks.

Comment: Dennis, $\partial (\omega _{IJ} dz^{I} \wedge dz^{\bar{J}} = \frac{\partial \omega _{IJ}}{\partial z^k} dz^k \wedge dz^{I} \wedge dz^{\bar{J}}$ and $\bar{\partial} (\omega _{IJ} dz^{I} \wedge dz^{\bar{J}} = \frac{\partial \omega _{IJ}}{\partial \bar{z}^k} d\bar{z}^k \wedge dz^{I} \wedge dz^{\bar{J}}$

Comment: Einstein summation implied above. Also $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$